# Navigation bar(dropdown) not working correctly?

Tags: javascript, css

The navigation bar was working fine before I added the background behind it.

http://essentialgroup.info/Memberarea.php

As you hover over one of the buttons, the drop down will appear detached from the menu, to the right.

I'm guessing I screwed the CSS up somewhere as I was messing with the background.

Hoping someone can shed some light on this, been driving me nuts trying to figure it out.

If anymore info is required let me know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your css seems broken.
In style.css i can see this:

```
{ background-atta
}
```

just under the `body{...}` section. Maybe something went wrong during copy-paste?

Comment: Hey there, how did I miss that! Thank you.. but unfortunately that hasn't fixed the problem. I think it may have something to do with the positioning being absolute?

Comment: the attributes "left" and "top" of your menu divs need to be corrected. for example, for the first menu list (Home) you have: 
`<div id="dropmenu1" class="dropmenudiv" style="height: auto; overflow: hidden; left: 244px; top: 397px; visibility: visible;">`
but should have `left:240` and `right:178`

Comment: i mean `left:240` and `top:178`

Comment: Doesn't seem to do the trick unfortunately.. I think this started when I added position:relative; to the menus parent div.. If i remove this the menu disapears.. Any idea?